# Why is 'max-width' ignored onto table-cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, w3c

Why does the `max-width` get ignored in the following table, once I add `display: table-row-group` to *header* and *body*?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header,
.body {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell" style="max-width: 4em;">
        content content content content content
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        content content content content content
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        content
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to control the min/max-size of cells into *body*, setting `min-`/`max-width` on the *head* cells (that doesn't necessarily need two rows as in the snippet).

What is happening here? What prevents the `max-width` to work?

Comment: Are you sure `4m` not  `4em` or  `4rem`? In general `min/max-width/height` is undefined in table.

Comment: ...unless `table-layout:fixed` is applied...and sometimes not even then.

Comment: If you set `.cell:first-child {max-width: 4em;}` it might work but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

“the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.” See  [definition of max-width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) in the CSS 2.1 spec.